# Nginx proxy configuration for offline app (appcache)

Tags: nginx, proxy, offline

I have an (online/offline) html app that works fine via Chrome (appcache). localhost:9999/ is served via Express.
After first load, it works well if the express server is offline.

Now I want the main html/css/js/png/... files gzipped via nginx proxy
localhost/ is served via nginx(as proxy) via a redirection to localhost:9999/.

It works well when the express server is online (gzipped).
It fails (Bad Gateway) when the server is offline.

Still looking for the right configuration ...
I'm not sure if nginx handles this well.

Thanks, Regards,
Gilles

Comment: I think this would be better for [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)